# Mobile devices unable to send mail due to servers sending quota being exceeded

Tags: exchange, email-server, email-bounces, mobile-devices, attachment

I have a customer who has their own exchange.
Their mobile devices are struggling to send emails with attachments and keep reporting that "your email server's sending quota has been exceeded".

I've checked the transport limits, the send and receive connector limits and the individual user limits, and I cant see why this would be occuring...

[image]

The individual limits are all set 'unlimited'.

Is there some other limits hidden away or any mobile device policy I've not taken into consideration?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I've just tried editing the 'maximum allowed content length' in IIS... I'll know in a few minutes if thats made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

As far as we know, mobile device usually use Exchange activesync protocol to connect exchange server.By default, there is no maxAllowedContentLength key in the web.config files for ActiveSync. However, the maximum message size for ActiveSync is affected by the maxAllowedContentLength value that is applied to all web sites on the server. The default value is 30000000 bytes. So,if the message size exceed this default limit, we will get the "exceed the quota" error.

Details see : [Configure client-specific message size limits](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh529949%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)